# list of node-opencv function names

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble locating the node-opencv equivalents of the functions in opencv 2.4. For instance, equalizeHist() is available. But I can't find can't find Scalar_ or GetMat().

I want a contrast function which is essentially Mat multiplied by Scalar. How do I find the equivalents in node-opencv to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, documentation is not directly outputed to README, but it is not trouble to dig in and find what is exported/supported. There are many examples in `examples` directory which can help a lot.

But searching through source code is more reliable:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:peterbraden/node-opencv.git
$ cd node-opencv
$ grep.exe -Rni "Nan::New" src | grep SetClassName
```

Output:

```
src/BackgroundSubtractor.cc:17:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("BackgroundSubtractor").ToLocalChecked());
src/CamShift.cc:20:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("TrackedObject").ToLocalChecked());
src/CascadeClassifierWrap.cc:14:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("CascadeClassifier").ToLocalChecked());
src/Contours.cc:16:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("Contours").ToLocalChecked());
src/FaceRecognizer.cc:36:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("FaceRecognizer").ToLocalChecked());
src/HighGUI.cc:14:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("NamedWindow").ToLocalChecked());
src/LDAWrap.cc:18:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("LDA").ToLocalChecked());
src/Matrix.cc:20:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("Matrix").ToLocalChecked());
src/Point.cc:13:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("Point").ToLocalChecked());
src/Stereo.cc:15:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("StereoBM").ToLocalChecked());
src/Stereo.cc:107:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("StereoSGBM").ToLocalChecked());
src/Stereo.cc:242:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("StereoGC").ToLocalChecked());
src/VideoCaptureWrap.cc:26:  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("VideoCapture").ToLocalChecked());
```

So we see `Matrix` is exported but `cv::Scalar` is not, but it is used many times in `Matrix.cc`.

To see which functions for `Matrix` or any other class are exported take a look at header file for macro `JSFUNC` or source file where `SetPrototypeMethod` is instance method and `SetMethod` is *static* method.